# Search Box Function Not Eliminating Correct Value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple website where the user types input into a search box, and every time a key is press, their input is compared against the first row of a 2 dimensional array which checks for character matches. If the character they input doesn't match anything, I want it to remove that specific bucket of the array. I have attempted to write basic code for this I thought would work, and have it up at the demo site linked. (Sorry I am just using a free host and havn't optimized the equation table at all so bear with it)

http://fakefakebuzz.0fees.net/

As you can see, the function is not eliminating the appropriate table rows. For example, typing "A" should not eliminate the "Average Current Equation" row because the first letter of that is A, which means matches should not = 0.

I have been looking through this code all morning, and cannot find where I went wrong. I also want to stick to vanilla js.

Any help?
Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you isolate the issue into a jsfiddle?

Comment: I tried putting it on jsfiddle and it wouldn't run properly. :/

Comment: you want do remove some indexes from a 2 dimensional array. am I right??

Comment: Yes! So for example, each array within it is referring to an equation name and the equation itself. If what the user typed matches no characters within the first bucket of the array, that entire array within the array needs to be removed.

Comment: check my answer out, I managed to go through your code and find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just debugged your code, and the function you use is `narrowTable`. first remove onkeypress from body node

```
<body onload="printTable()" onkeypress="narrowTable()">
```

and add onkeyup instead to you input, like this:

```
<input type="search" name="equationSearch" id="equationSearch"
      placeholder="Equation Search" autofocus="" onkeyup="narrowTable()">
```

because when you use onkeypress the key value hasn't been added to the input box and your `input` value has no value in your function, which is:

```
function narrowTable() {
    var newTableContent = "";
    var matches = 0;
    var input = document.getElementById("equationSearch").value;
    //input has no value
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tableData[i][0].length; j++) {
            if (input == tableData[i][0].charAt(j)) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        if (matches == 0) {
            tableData.splice(i, 1);
        }
        matches = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        newTableContent += "<tr><td>" + tableData[i][0] + "</td><td>" + tableData[i][1] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = newTableContent;

}
```

the other problem your code has is after printing your table, your `tableData` variable has changed because you have removed some of indexes. you should reset the `tableData` to its original value or you can do:

```
function narrowTable() {
    //create a copy of your original array and use currenttableData instead
    var currenttableData = tableData.slice();
    var newTableContent = "";
    var matches = 0;
    //your code
}
```

the other problem here is the way you search for your input value:

```
for (var j = 0; j < tableData[i][0].length; j++) {
    if (input == tableData[i][0].charAt(j)) {
        matches++;
    }
}
if (matches == 0) {
    tableData.splice(i, 1);
}
```

you can easily do this, instead:

```
if(tableData[i][0].search("input") == -1){
    tableData.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: I think yours is working on the first character, but on characters after it goes wrong. This is likely because of my implementation and something I can fix. Thanks though!

Comment: Actually it is not my code, it is your exact code, but I can offer you some points to fix your `narrowTable` function, which has some critical points, but i think now you can fix it yourself. and if it was your answer, would you accept it.

Comment: Sure! And hey I'd love some pointers, I'm just trying to learn programming more in depth than some of the websites that say "Enter this to do this!" Is there a way you can get in touch with me and just walk me through this function? I can tell something is still wrong because when I type the letter 'z', rows that still have z's don't go away.

Comment: when you type letter `Z` what has to happen?

Comment: Well if I were to search for z, you would expect every array element to be deleted and the table to be empty, since none of tableData[i][0] contain a z character. This does not happen however.

Answer (score 1):

First, to check if a string is a substring of another string, you can use `indexOf`. It will return `-1` if the string is not found in the other string.

Second, you shouldn't alter the array while you are still looping through it, unless you make sure to alter the counter variable (`i` in this case) appropriately.

```
var dataToRemove = [],
    i;

for (i=0; i<tableData.length; i++) {
    if(tableData[i][0].indexOf(input) == -1) {
        // add the index to the to-be-removed array
        dataToRemove.push(i);
}

// remove them in reverse order, so the indices don't get shifted as the array gets smaller
for(i = dataToRemove.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tableData.splice(i, 1);
}
dataToRemove = [];

for (i=0; i<tableData.length; i++) {
    newTableContent += "<tr><td>" + tableData[i][0] + "</td><td>" + tableData[i][1] + "</td></tr>";
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should at least give you a better idea of how to make this work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably end up using your code with Mehrans event. Thanks for explaining so well though!